# Type mismatch when checking if values are found in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if the values of some cells in a column are found in another sheet within the same workbook. If it is found then the original cell is highlighted green, if not it is highlighted red. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookup()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Sheets("Zach Spares").Select
    
    For i = 8 To 1035

    ' the next line is the one that gives me the error
    Set rng = Sheets("SAP Spares").Range("G5:G6446").Find(Cells(i, 6).Value)
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
            Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I keep getting

> Run-time Error '13': Type Mismatch.

on the line after the comment. This code worked for well over half of the data, now it wont work anymore. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to fix the mismatch.

I tried adding

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
    Set rng = Sheets("SAP Spares").Range("G5:G6446").Find(Cells(i, 6).Value)
    End If
```

To catch any cells that might contain an error but I am still getting the same type mismatch. It is worth mentioning that the script works for columns 1-5, at 6 it starts to mess up and I do not know why.
[image: Error message]

[image: My code as a whole, VBA showing the wrong part]

Comment: Check whether one or more cells in Column F in your sheet called Zach Spares contains an error value of some type.

Comment: ^^ Can you let us know what `Cells(i, 6).Value` returns the second your code errors out? Since you tagged, `Excel-formula` I suspect exactly what @Domenic mentioned.

Comment: @Domenic this is right. You should add it as an answer.

Comment: I checked all the values but there was not an error. That was also my first assumption

Answer (score 0):

As flagged by @Domenic in the comments below the question, this can occur if the cell being accessed has an error.

You may use the IsError function to check for this, so that the code can highlight the error cells in a different colour and continue:

```
    If IsError(Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G5:G6446").Find(Cells(i, 6).Value)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried the snipped of code you mentioned but unfortunately I still run into the same error

Comment: @ahmedgad you have added your `End If` in the wrong place. This would explain why you still get the same error. Please refer again to my answer.